# is there a maximum assignable memory for a windows service

Tags: windows, jboss, windows-server-2008-r2

I would like to know if there is a maximum assignable memory for a windows service (Windows Server 2008R2). The context is:

1. JBoss AS 6.1.0 running over a Windows Server 2008R2
2. JBoss is started as service with `JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512M -Xmx3072M -XX:MaxPermSize=3072M`

I don't see that JBoss takes more than 2Gb and I would like to know if windows could be limiting the amount of available memory for the process, and how to avoid it if that is happening.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, Windows does not treat service processes any differently to other applications in terms of memory allocation.  Have you checked that the process is 64-bit?

Comment: Yes, I have. The process that is running is a instance of java.exe, of a 64-bit installation. Thanx for the answer.